# How to disable GUI in Debian 11 but I want to be able to open application level GUI e.g. QTCreator

Tags: linux, debian

I want to disable the main GUI in Debian 11 (not sure if this the correct term) so that the default login UI and other things does not come. Sort of Text login. (For this I was able to find the answer)

But after login I want to be able to open terminal and some applications GUI. It is needed to debug the code e.g QTCreator.

How to do that ?

PS : I have extensively searched but I am not able to find the solution, it could be due to I am not knowing terms with which I need to search.

Comment: Wouldn't it be sufficient to switch to text-console (`ctrl-alt-F[1-6]`), do the work, and switch back to X via `ctrl-alt-F7` when a GUI is needed?

Comment: It will not help because I must be able to open application GUI in this case QtCreator to debug the code.